# Feature maps of the chi-squared kernel

Tags: machine-learning, kernel-trick, chi-squared-distribution

The additive chi-squared kernel for histograms is defined as
$$K(x,y)= \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{2x_i y_i}{x_i + y_i}$$ Is this kernel positive definite on histograms? And if so, is there a known expression for its feature map? It does not have to be the canonical feature map mapping to the RKHS associated with $K$, just any (possibly data-dependent) map would be fine.

Remark: Once we have a feature map for $K(x,y) = \frac{2xy}{x+y}$, we can simply concatenate it appropriately to get a feature map for the additive version.

Comment: Are you sure you have the right kernel? sklearn [says](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.pairwise.chi2_kernel.html): "The chi-squared kernel is given by:" ` k(x, y) = exp(-gamma Sum [(x - y)^2 / (x + y)])`.

And a quick check using some (positive) random numbers shows plenty of negative eigenvalues for your version?

Comment: Honestly, I am confused now. There seem to be multiple notions of the chi-squared kernel (though I do not mean the kernel you linked). I was talking about the one used for histograms (have updated my question). Unfortunately sklearn has yet another version https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.pairwise.additive_chi2_kernel.html

Comment: 1) Okay, I get that feeling too. 2) Do you know whether the additive chi-squared kernel I linked (sklearn version) is positive definite?

Comment: I think you should edit to reflect the different question. The sklearn docs actually answer this. At the end under *Notes* They say "As the negative of a distance, this kernel is only conditionally positive definite."

Comment: I updated the question. Thanks for pointing out that the sklearn version of the kernel is CPD.

Comment: I get a minimum eigenvalue of 0 for the kernel matrix for multiple randomly sampled histograms. Did you consider that histograms are positive?

Comment: Sorry, you are right. I screwed up my test.